# Densely defined operator

Tags: operator-theory

let $X$ Hilbert space and $A$ an nonlinear operator such that:

$$A:D(A)\subset X \rightarrow X$$
Is this implication is true?

$A$ is m-dissipative $\implies A$ is densely defined.

I know that is true for the linear operator..if the last implication is false, what is the hypothesis that we have to add to the m-dissipativity to have a true implication ?

Comment: maybe this paper will help, see section 6 https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82753147.pdf